# Serialize object without including property names

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

I have a simple object:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember(Name = "MyClassNo")]
    public int MyClassNo { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "MyName")]
    public string MyName { get; set; }
 }
```

When I serialize it over my web service I get

```
[
  {"MyClassNo": 1, "MyName": "Test1"},
  {"MyClassNo": 2, "MyName": "Test2"}
]
```

But what I want is the data without the property names included:

```
[
  {1, "Test1"},
  {2, "Test2"}
]
```

How do I achieve this?

*Edit - The Code I use to serialize is:

```
var myObj = MyOpenSQlConnection.Query<MyClass>(@"select MyClassNo, MyName from MyTable");
return myObj.ToList<MyClass>();
```

Note that I'm using [Dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) to map the sql results to my object

Comment: Do you have a code of serializer which service is using? It seems a JSON format

Comment: `{1, "Test1"}` this is invalid JSON

Comment: The choice of dapper is excellent (biased ;p), but shouldn't affect serialization at all in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to do this without writing your own serializer that serializes to something other than a property hash. Hashes are sequences of key-value fields and therefore must have unique keys for each field.

If you tried blank values for each key, as in:

```
{"": "apple", "": "banana", "": "coconut"}
```

then what you really have is just:

```
{"": "coconut"}
```

since each key will overwrite the one before it.

A better question is probably, "why do you want to serialize without the property names?" Especially in web-based environments, you're going to want to know which value corresponds to which field.

Comment: It is looking like I need to write my own serializer, I was hoping there would be one out of the box! In answer to your second question: I really don't want to start a bun fight about this but I want to transmit as few bytes as possible while not compressing the data.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify to all members this attibute: [DataMember(Name = "REMOVEME")]
and then replace it by empty string :)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, When I do that I get a Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): : The server closed the connection without sending any data.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarentee that `MyClassNo` is **always** distinct then you could return a `Dictionary<int, string>` instead if a `List<MyClass>` which may be more along the lines of what you are after.

Comment: OK my example was simplified, some of my object have 60+ properties so I'm not sure I could use a dictionary.